# Playing audio from array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, audio, codepen

I'm currently working on a small personal project as a gag for a friend. I'm using codepen.io as my platform to host the project since it is only a single page. Lastly I'm new to JavaScript so please dumb it down as much as possible or include a source for additional reference if possible, I'd greatly appreciate it!

**The script** 
It must pick a random audio file from an array and play it when clicked, without automaticly playing the next one. It should be 100% random every time. Eventually, I would like to add weighted values.

**The Problem**

I have looked online for almost a week now to find how to use youtube url's as just audio in an array, but it doesn't seem possible. So how would I go about uploading these audio files to the page and addingthem to the array? Would you use the `<audio src="url" id="itemOne">` and format the array like `var playList [ document.getElementById="itemOne", document.getElementById="itemTwo" ]`?

**Source Information**
[CodePen.io Project](https://codepen.io/Gfregan3/pen/gBKzoN?editors=0010)
*JavaScript Code*

```js
var button = document.getElementById("playbutton")

button.onclick = function() {

  function getRandomTrackNumber(list) {

    const min = 0,
      max = playList.length;

    const trackNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

    return trackNumber;
  }

  let nextSong = playList[getRandomTrackNumber(playList)]
  //index.js: Unexpected token, expected } (17:0)

  nextSong.play();
}
```

Thanks In Advance!
~George
Edit: First Problem Solved

Comment: Code in your post has no syntax errors..... Have not looked at the link....

Comment: here on SO each question should be razor sharp and pointed to a single issue ... do not conflate ... adhering to this maximizes the S/N ratio when folks search and land on a question ... anything beyond a single issue should become a new question ... welcome to SO

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<script>` and `</script>` tags in your JS section. That at least fixes your current issue.

Comment: Well that fixed the error. It's always something super simple lmao. Any clue about the array?

Comment: I don't have much experience with audio in HTML. However I do know there's a youtube video embedded player. Maybe have one of those, that autoplays, and is hidden. Change url based on random chosen value? You can probably make the html element hidden (visibility:hidden do not use display:none)? Good luck.